# Using .htaccess to redirect a directory with or without a trailing slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I think this is a dumb question but I am completely stuck.  I've moved a server but need my .htaccess file to point to some legacy folders on the old server.

I have redirects set up that work correctly:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ~username 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://old.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This takes https://**new**.domain.com/~username and points it to https://**old**.domain.com/~username PERFECT

But if someone enters:

https://new.domain.com/~username/ (*with* the trailing slash)

the URL resolves to:

http://old.domain.com/https://new.domain.com/ip/webmastername/wwws/~username/

How can I write my RewriteCond to include an optional trailing slash and then use that in the RewriteRule?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try replacing `/$1` with `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your rule on top of .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^~username/?$ https://old.domain.com/~username [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```